# What's are possible alternatives to do screencast from Google Glass on desktop?

Tags: android, google-glass

During Google Glass presentations you can see that Googlers are using some nice java app for screencasting their screen from Glass. App's ID is `com.google.glass.screencast`. However I couldn't find source or jar to download anywhere.

So far I found [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/), which works fine but lacks couple nice features from above app. Do you found any other interesting alternatives more suitable for Glass presentations?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best solution out there but in the past I have used [Android Screen monitor](https://code.google.com/p/android-screen-monitor/) for Glass screencasting and it worked pretty well.